# Cannot group values based on specific string in MongoDB using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've a usecase where I'm having 3 collections. i.e, Templates,Groups and 1-dynamic collection of each template, which will be created right after the creation of a template.

Each template consists of `devices` and each `device` consists of a `groupId` of Groups collection. Dynamic collection stores the data pushed by the template's devices.

Following are the sample data of my collections.

**Template Data**

```
{
  "_id": "5e0ae38729218b0a3861118b",
  "templateId": "13435158964",
  "devices": [
    {
      "deviceId": "a-1",
      "_id": "5e0ae49629218b0a3861118f",
      "group": "5e0ae41d29218b0a3861118d",
    },{
       "deviceId": "sb-0001",
       "_id": "5e0af166981f39410cd89b72",
       "group": "5e0af11d981f39410cd89b70"
    }]
}
```

**Dynamic Collection Data**

```
[
  {
      "_id": "5e0ae793b1384737a4f855cf",
      "template": "13435158964",
      "deviceId": "a-1",
      "heat": 30,
      "humidity": 40
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e0ae7a2b1384737a4f855d0",
      "template": "13435158964",
      "deviceId": "sb-0001",
      "heat": 40,
      "humidity": 20
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e0ae890b1384737a4f855d3",
      "template": "13435158964",
      "deviceId": "a-1",
      "heat": 10,
      "humidity": 20
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e0af188981f39410cd89b73",
      "template": "13435158964",
      "deviceId": "a-1",
      "heat": 60,
      "humidity": 50
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e0af196981f39410cd89b74",
      "template": "13435158964",
      "deviceId": "sb-0001",
      "heat": 15,
      "humidity": 25
    }]
```

**Group Data**

```
[{
   "_id": "5e0af11d981f39410cd89b70",
   "template": "5e0ae38729218b0a3861118b",
   "groupName": "Flats"
 },{
    "_id": "5e0ae41d29218b0a3861118d",
    "template": "5e0ae38729218b0a3861118b",
    "groupName": "Swimming Pool"
 }]
```

So for the above data, I am trying to get the sum of heat and humidity for the `groupName` specified. 
So the expected output should be :

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Swimming Pool",
    "heat": 110,
    "humidity": 165,
    "count":2
  },{
    "_id": "Flat",
    "heat": 70,
    "humidity": 80,
    "count":1
  }]
```

**Returned Output **

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Swimming Pool",
    "heat": 180,
    "humidity": 245,
    "count":2
  },{
    "_id": "Flat",
    "heat": 180,
    "humidity": 245,
    "count":1
  }]
```

I'm not sure how to achieve that, Can any one help me solve the issue

***My Query:*** 
Here, templates and groups are different collections.

```
db.getCollection('13435158964').aggregate([
{ "$match": {"entryDayTime":{
                    $lt: new Date("2019-11-29T18:30:00.000Z"),
                    $gte: new Date("2019-10-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                }
}
},{
    $lookup:{
        from:"templates",
        localField:"template",
        foreignField:"templateId",
        as:"templateData"
    }
},{
    $unwind:"$templateData"
},{
    $unwind:"$templateData.devices"
},{
    $lookup:{
       from:"groups",
       localField:"templateData.devices.group",
       foreignField:"_id",
       as:"groupData"
     }
},{
    $unwind:"$groupData"
},{
    $group:{
       _id: "$groupData.groupName",
       heat:{$sum:"$heat"},
       humidity:{$sum:"$humidity"},
       count:{$sum:1}
    }
},{
    $project:{
       "count":1,"heat":1,"humidity":1,"templateData.devices.group":1,"templateData.devices.deviceId":1,"groupData.groupName":1
}
}])
```

Comment: _Cannot group values ..._: What is the issue? Here is an [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#calculate-count-sum-and-average) on how to _count_ and _sum_ using `$group`.

Comment: _"templates and groups are different collections."_: Please post the structures of both the collections (and title them).

Comment: @prasad_ I have updated the question, please check it now.

Comment: @prasad_ please check this one  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561287/10465501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I understood, you were expecting the data grouped by group names. But you were getting wrong results.

So for that, please refer this following aggregation code.

```
db.getCollection('13435158964').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "templates",
      localField: "template",
      foreignField: "templateId",
      as: "templateData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$templateData"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$templateData.devices"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$deviceId",
          "$templateData.devices.deviceId"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "groups",
      localField: "templateData.devices.group",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "groupData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$groupData"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$groupData.groupName",
      heat: {
        "$sum": "$heat"
      },
      humidity: {
        "$sum": "$humidity"
      },
      count: {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You will get the answer something like this,

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Swimming Pool",
    "count": 3,
    "heat": 100,
    "humidity": 110
  },
  {
    "_id": "Flats",
    "count": 2,
    "heat": 55,
    "humidity": 45
  }
]
```

You can refer to this link too,  https://mongoplayground.net/p/hr95U1eT5bL

Answer (score 0):

A simple [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage should do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$groupData.groupName",
            heat: {$sum: "$heat"},
            humidity: {$sum: "$humidity"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I have already tried that but it was giving the duplicate values. For ex, if we take ```heat of Flat group```, it's giving the sum of ```heat``` of all other groups as well. i.e, sum of heat of all groups is displaying in every group.

Comment: Thats not possible, i recommend you look at the raw data to verify you need a different result than what your getting.

Comment: its hard to tell without seeing the data, but with ur current query you risk "looking up" multiple instances of the same document, this might be the reason why your not getting the result you expect.

Comment: please check this one 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561287/10465501

Comment: its working as expected, all the data shares the same template ID meaning they're gonna get duplicated exactly the same. the problem is not the group but how you built your data.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the clarification @tom slabbaert. I think, matching the deviceId of dynamic collection with the deviceId of Template collection would resolve this issue. D you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$group` stage of mongo pipeline framework. Something like this should work

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$groupData.groupName",
        "humidity": {
            "$sum": "$humidity"
        },
        "heat": {
            "$sum": "$heat"
        },
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}])
```